# asp .net core app on IIS --> Could not load file or assembly System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, deployment, windows-forms-core

I have an Asp .Net core project with

```
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

Trying to deploy this project to IIS with following settings

```
 <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
 <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
```

On the server, asp .net core hosting bundle is installed.

However, when the function which requires windows forms assemblies is called, following error is thrown:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, >Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find >the file specified.

EDIT:

So the question is if any component is built on a different version like 6.0.2.0, how is it resolved on IIS ? Do we have to have a redirection file like in old times?

Comment: Why would you be trying to use Windows Forms in an ASP.NET Core app in the first place?

Comment: Good question, there are some dependencies (like reporting) that use it.

Comment: What do you mean by that? What reporting? If you're talking about the Microsoft ReportViewer control then there are separate web and Windows versions.

Comment: This one, to be precise: https://www.grapecity.com/componentone/flexreport-net-reporting-engine .

Comment: I don't have time to look into that in depth but I find it hard to believe that it specifically supports ASP.NET MVC, as it says on that home page, but requires a reference to WinForms. It's extremely poorly designed if it does. I suspect that you have done something wrong, but I don't have the time or inclination to try to confirm it.

Comment: There are many components that still do, and hopefully are under process of migration. On top of that there is the versioning issue, in that some of the components are built on an updated version like 6.0.2.

Comment: Does your project work locally? or does this error only appear after it is deployed to IIS?

Comment: Works locally. Error appears only after deployment on IIS.

Comment: The solution to this problem is to `enable 32-bit Applications` in Application Pool of IIS Server. Right-click on the Application Tool and choose Advanced Settings. In the Advanced Settings window, under the General section, click on the dropdown behind Enable 32-Bit Applications option and select True.

Comment: Tried and got the following error: 


HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime
Common solutions to this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
Specific error detected by ANCM:
You must install or update .NET to run this application. App: C:\inetpub\Powerbom\ETO.Web.Core.dll Architecture: x86 Framework: 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '6.0.0' (x86) .NET location: C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\ No frameworks were found.

Comment: Can you find information about System.Windows.Forms? It may also be related to the version of TargetFramework, you can try to change it to `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>` and try again.